# DropdownlistFor onchange event is not working

Tags: onchange, dropdownlistfor

I have a dropdownlisfor in my mvc project. I added onchange event to dropdownlistfor but it didn't work. I don't understand where I made mistake. Can you help me?

Here is Dropdownlistfor:

```
<span id="span1">
            @{
                string birth_Date = null;
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Birth_Date,
         new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)DoctorDatawarehouse.Business.CommonChoiceList.LoadYearList(), "Value", "Text", birth_Date, new { onchange = "HideSecond()" } ))

            }
                </span>
```

Then here is triggered onchange function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideSecond()
    {
        alert('deneme');
        document.getElementById("span2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Yeni Doktor Kaydı</title>

    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">

                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="/NewDoctor/Create">Yeni Doktor Kaydı</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <section id="login">


    <ul>
        <li><a href="/Account/Create" id="registerLink">&#220;ye Olma</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Account/Login" id="loginLink">Giriş</a></li>
    </ul>

                </section>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">

        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">


<h2>Doktor Bilgi Formu</h2>





<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideSecond() {
        alert('Tarih gizlendi.');
        document.getElementById("span2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    function HideFirst() {
        alert('Tarih aralığı gizlendi.');
        document.getElementById("span1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

</script>

<form action="/NewDoctor/Create" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="nZVU-_ynRW6zacl91y__lXRfmcKbisNZUgiOKr9FlM9AP71zCniulgUpk_yYPlkxmr_NNn576KAf-b5lEaVzg0YPD8AOH8DrVqV8x0ChAJo1" />    <fieldset>
    <table>


        <tr>
            <td><label for="Name">Ad Soyad</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="İsmi 3-50 karakter arasında girebilirsiniz." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Lütfen isim giriniz!" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Birth_Date">Doğum Tarihi / Tahmini Yaş Aralığı</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
                <span id="span1">
<select id="Birth_Date" name="Birth_Date"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1900">1900</option>
<option value="1901">1901</option>
<option value="1902">1902</option>
<option value="1903">1903</option>
<option value="1904">1904</option>
<option value="1905">1905</option>
<option value="1906">1906</option>
<option value="1907">1907</option>
<option value="1908">1908</option>
<option value="1909">1909</option>
<option value="1910">1910</option>
<option value="1911">1911</option>
<option value="1912">1912</option>
<option value="1913">1913</option>
<option value="1914">1914</option>
<option value="1915">1915</option>
<option value="1916">1916</option>
<option value="1917">1917</option>
<option value="1918">1918</option>
<option value="1919">1919</option>
<option value="1920">1920</option>
<option value="1921">1921</option>
<option value="1922">1922</option>
<option value="1923">1923</option>
<option value="1924">1924</option>
<option value="1925">1925</option>
<option value="1926">1926</option>
<option value="1927">1927</option>
<option value="1928">1928</option>
<option value="1929">1929</option>
<option value="1930">1930</option>
<option value="1931">1931</option>
<option value="1932">1932</option>
<option value="1933">1933</option>
<option value="1934">1934</option>
<option value="1935">1935</option>
<option value="1936">1936</option>
<option value="1937">1937</option>
<option value="1938">1938</option>
<option value="1939">1939</option>
<option value="1940">1940</option>
<option value="1941">1941</option>
<option value="1942">1942</option>
<option value="1943">1943</option>
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
<option value="1991">1991</option>
<option value="1992">1992</option>
<option value="1993">1993</option>
<option value="1994">1994</option>
<option value="1995">1995</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
                </span>
                <span id="span2">
<select id="Town" name="Town"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1989">20-30</option>
<option value="1979">30-40</option>
<option value="1969">40-50</option>
<option value="1959">50-60</option>
<option value="1949">60+</option>
</select>
                </span>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Birth_Date" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Gender">Cinsiyet</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="Lütfen cinsiyet bilgisini giriniz!" id="Gender" name="Gender"><option value="K">Kadın</option>
<option value="E">Erkek</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Gender" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Country">İkamet Ettiği &#220;lke</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
            <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Ülke ismini 3-25 karakter arasında girebilirsiniz." data-val-length-max="25" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Lütfen ülke bilgisini giriniz!" id="Country" name="Country" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Country" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="City">İkamet Ettiği İl</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<select id="City" name="City"><option value="01        ">Adana</option>
<option value="02        ">Adıyaman</option>
<option value="03        ">Afyon</option>
<option value="04        ">Ağrı</option>
<option value="05        ">Amasya</option>
<option value="06        ">Ankara</option>
<option value="07        ">Antalya</option>
<option value="08        ">Artvin</option>
<option value="09        ">Aydın</option>
<option value="10        ">Balıkesir</option>
<option value="11        ">Bilecik</option>
<option value="12        ">Bing&#246;l</option>
<option value="13        ">Bitlis</option>
<option value="14        ">Bolu</option>
<option value="15        ">Burdur</option>
<option value="16        ">Bursa</option>
<option value="17        ">&#199;anakkale</option>
<option value="18        ">&#199;ankırı</option>
<option value="19        ">&#199;orum</option>
<option value="20        ">Denizli</option>
<option value="21        ">Diyarbakır</option>
<option value="22        ">Edirne</option>
<option value="23        ">Elazığ</option>
<option value="24        ">Erzincan</option>
<option value="25        ">Erzurum</option>
<option value="26        ">Eskişehir</option>
<option value="27        ">Gaziantep</option>
<option value="28        ">Giresun</option>
<option value="29        ">G&#252;m&#252;şhane</option>
<option value="30        ">Hakkari</option>
<option value="31        ">Hatay</option>
<option value="32        ">Isparta</option>
<option value="33        ">Mersin</option>
<option value="34        ">İstanbul</option>
<option value="35        ">İzmir</option>
<option value="36        ">Kars</option>
<option value="37        ">Kastamonu</option>
<option value="38        ">Kayseri</option>
<option value="39        ">Kırklareli</option>
<option value="40        ">Kırşehir</option>
<option value="41        ">Kocaeli</option>
<option value="42        ">Konya</option>
<option value="43        ">K&#252;tahya</option>
<option value="44        ">Malatya</option>
<option value="45        ">Manisa</option>
<option value="46        ">K.Maraş</option>
<option value="47        ">Mardin</option>
<option value="48        ">Muğla</option>
<option value="49        ">Muş</option>
<option value="50        ">Nevşehir</option>
<option value="51        ">Niğde</option>
<option value="52        ">Ordu</option>
<option value="53        ">Rize</option>
<option value="54        ">Sakarya</option>
<option value="55        ">Samsun</option>
<option value="56        ">Siirt</option>
<option value="57        ">Sinop</option>
<option value="58        ">Sivas</option>
<option value="59        ">Tekirdağ</option>
<option value="60        ">Tokat</option>
<option value="61        ">Trabzon</option>
<option value="62        ">Tunceli</option>
<option value="63        ">Şanlıurfa</option>
<option value="64        ">Uşak</option>
<option value="65        ">Van</option>
<option value="66        ">Yozgat</option>
<option value="67        ">Zonguldak</option>
<option value="68        ">Aksaray</option>
<option value="69        ">Bayburt</option>
<option value="70        ">Karaman</option>
<option value="71        ">Kırıkkale</option>
<option value="72        ">Batman</option>
<option value="73        ">Şırnak</option>
<option value="74        ">Bartın</option>
<option value="75        ">Ardahan</option>
<option value="76        ">Iğdır</option>
<option value="77        ">Yalova</option>
<option value="78        ">Karab&#252;k</option>
<option value="79        ">Kilis</option>
<option value="80        ">Osmaniye</option>
<option value="81        ">D&#252;zce</option>
<option value="99        ">Yurtdışı - Diğer</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Speciality">Uzmanlığı</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Uzmanlığı must be a number." data-val-required="Lütfen uzmanlık bilgisini giriniz!" id="Speciality" name="Speciality"><option value="1">G&#246;z Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="2">Hematoloji</option>
<option value="3">Acil Tıp</option>
<option value="4">Ağız ve Diş Sağlığı</option>
<option value="5">Aile Hekimliği</option>
<option value="6">Anestezi ve Reanimasyon</option>
<option value="7">Beslenme ve Diyetetik</option>
<option value="8">Beyin ve Sinir Cerrahisi</option>
<option value="9">Biyokimya</option>
<option value="10">&#199;ocuk Cerrahisi</option>
<option value="11">&#199;ocuk Sağlığı ve Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="12">Dermatoloji</option>
<option value="13">Enfeksiyon Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="14">Fiziksel Tıp ve Rehabilitasyon</option>
<option value="15">Genel Yoğun Bakım</option>
<option value="16">Ortopedi ve Travmatoloji</option>
<option value="17">G&#246;ğ&#252;s Cerrahisi</option>
<option value="18">Plastik, Rekonstr&#252;ktif ve Estetik Cerrahi</option>
<option value="19">Tıbbi Onkoloji</option>
<option value="20">Kadın Hastalıkları ve Doğum</option>
<option value="21">Genel Cerrahi</option>
<option value="22">Kalp ve Damar Cerrahisi</option>
<option value="23">Kardiyoloji</option>
<option value="24">Pratisyen Hekimlik</option>
<option value="25">N&#246;roloji</option>
<option value="26">Kulak-Burun-Boğaz Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="27">G&#246;ğ&#252;s Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="28">N&#252;kleer Tıp</option>
<option value="29">İ&#231; Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="30">Psikoloji</option>
<option value="31">Psikiyatri</option>
<option value="32">Radyasyon Onkolojisi</option>
<option value="33">Enfeksiyon Hastalıkları ve Klinik Mikrobiyoloji</option>
<option value="34">Halk Sağlığı</option>
<option value="35">Patoloji</option>
<option value="36">Radyoloji</option>
<option value="37">Tıbbi Genetik</option>
<option value="38">T&#252;p Bebek  (IVF)</option>
<option value="39">&#220;roloji</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Speciality" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Sub_Branch">Yan Dal Uzmanlığı</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Yan Dal Uzmanlığı must be a number." id="Sub_Branch" name="Sub_Branch"><option value="">Yok</option>
<option value="1">Algoloji</option>
<option value="2">Cerrahi Onkoloji</option>
<option value="3">&#199;ocuk Acil</option>
<option value="4">&#199;ocuk Endokrinolojisi ve Metabolizma Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="5">&#199;ocuk Enfeksiyon Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="6">&#199;ocuk Gastroenteroloji</option>
<option value="7">&#199;ocuk Genetik Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="8">&#199;ocuk G&#246;ğ&#252;s Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="9">&#199;ocuk Hematolojisi ve Onkolojisi</option>
<option value="10">&#199;ocuk İmm&#252;nolojisi ve Alerji Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="11">&#199;ocuk Kalp ve Damar Cerrahisi</option>
<option value="12">&#199;ocuk Kardiyolojisi</option>
<option value="13">&#199;ocuk Nefrolojisi</option>
<option value="14">&#199;ocuk N&#246;rolojisi</option>
<option value="15">&#199;ocuk Romatolojisi</option>
<option value="16">&#199;ocuk &#220;rolojisi</option>
<option value="17">&#199;ocuk Yoğun Bakımı</option>
<option value="18">El Cerrahisi</option>
<option value="19">Endokrinoloji ve Metabolizma Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="20">Gastroenteroloji</option>
<option value="22">Geatri</option>
<option value="23">Hematoloji</option>
<option value="24">İmm&#252;noloji ve Alerji Hastalıkları</option>
<option value="25">Jinekolojik Onkoloji </option>
<option value="26">Nefroloji</option>
<option value="27">Neonatoloji</option>
<option value="28">Perinatoloji</option>
<option value="29">Romatoloji</option>
<option value="30">Temel İmm&#252;noloji</option>
<option value="31">Tıbbi Parazitoloji</option>
<option value="32">Tıbbi Viroloji</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Sub_Branch" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Academic_Appellation">Akademik &#220;nvanı</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Akademik Ünvanı must be a number." data-val-required="Lütfen akademik ünvan bilgisini giriniz!" id="Academic_Appellation" name="Academic_Appellation"><option selected="selected" value="0">Yok</option>
<option value="1">Yrd. Do&#231;</option>
<option value="2">Do&#231;</option>
<option value="3">Prof.</option>
</select>
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Academic_Appellation" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>



         <tr>
            <td><label for="is_Special_Notes">&#214;zel Not</label></td>
             <td>
            <span class="editor-field">*
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Özel Not must be a number." data-val-required="The Özel Not field is required." id="is_Special_Notes" name="is_Special_Notes"><option value="1">Var</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0">Yok</option>
</select>
        </span>
              <span class="editor-field">
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="Special_Notes" name="Special_Notes" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Special_Notes" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Communication">Hekime Nasıl Ulaşılacak</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">&nbsp
            <input class="text-box single-line" id="Communication" name="Communication" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Communication" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Person_Name">Formu Dolduranın Adı Soyadı</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Adınızı 3-50 karakter arasında girebilirsiniz." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length-min="3" data-val-required="Lütfen adınızı giriniz!" id="Person_Name" name="Person_Name" type="text" value="" />            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Person_Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label for="Person_Email">Formu Dolduranın E-posta Adresi</label></td>
            <td><div class="editor-field">*
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Lütfen e-posta adresinizi giriniz." id="Person_Email" name="Person_Email" type="email" value="" />            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Person_Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                * ile belirtilen alanlar için veri girişi zorunludur.
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>


        <p><input type="submit" value="Kaydet" name="Kaydet" onclick="ShowHide()"></p>

    </fieldset>
</form>
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>&copy; 2014 - MedicalPark</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try replacing the onchange event binding to a simple alert; onchange="alert('hello');".  Does this work?

Comment: I tried onchange="alert('hello');" , but it didn't work again. I wonder if I made mistake on writing?

Comment: Please post the resultant HTML.  i.e., view in the browser, view source and copy and paste that code into your question. thanks

Comment: Because of a haven't 10 reputation and because of i am new in stackoverflow i can't add image. But in this link there is an image about it : http://i.stack.imgur.com/pJBkv.png

I want to hide one dropdownlist if I choose item from another dropdownlist.

Comment: No problem; however, I need the HTML source rather than a screen shot.  So right click on your page, copy and paste the html onto the clipboard and paste into your question (at the moment you have the ASP.NET source, rather than the actual rendered html)

Comment: I posted HTML source like you said. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were putting the `onchange` html attributes object inside the constructor for the SelectList rather than putting it in the appropriate `DropDownListFor` method parameter.
Replace

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Birth_Date,
     new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)DoctorDatawarehouse.Business.CommonChoiceList.LoadYearList(), "Value", "Text", birth_Date, new { onchange = "HideSecond()" } ))
```

With

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Birth_Date, 
new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)DoctorDatawarehouse.Business.CommonChoiceList.LoadYearList(), "Value", "Text", birth_Date), 
new { onchange = "HideSecond()" })
```